# Issue with Timestamp Field When Importing Google Sheet to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a large Google Sheets file to Big query.I am attempting to upload a large file from Google Sheets into BigQuery. During this process, I'm facing challenges with the TIMESTAMP field. Despite converting it to various formats, an error persists.When I choose to exclude the TIMESTAMP column during the upload, it seems the query remains influenced by this column, causing the same error to appear.

this is the Error:

```
while reading table: kostore-402516.KO.Order_Details, error message: Could not convert        value to     timestamp. Error: Could not parse '9/20/2023 15:38:17' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]] or YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]. Row 11513; Col 43. File:        1vU1jivBNm0WFz0TMKDmCo3LONp2itNlmj-cWn8ZSFXc
```

Moreover, when I try to manually define the schema (bypassing the automatic detection), I face a similar error.

Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

1.[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gNX2.png)

2. [The problematic column on google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nigIZ.png)

3. [The schema on bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xSPL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [Timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) format is very particular - it has to be YYYY-mm-dd for a start (your date is YYYY/mm/dd).

Try the [DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) type, it's much more forgiving when parsing from Sheets.